# Comparing enumerations on the same infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Given two enumerations $A:S \to \mathbb{N}$, $B:S \to \mathbb{N}$ on the same countably infinite set $S$, are there infinitely many elements $s \in S$ with $A(s) \geq B(s)$?

My feeling is that there must be, i.e. that it cannot be the case that all but a finite number of elements of S appear in B before A, but I can't come up with a proof to support this feeling.

Am I correct? If so, could I have a hint for a proof?

Comment: What is definition of A-index and B-index?

Comment: I mean the position of the element in the total orders A and B, if we consider the total orders as enumerations of S.

Comment: Somehow I don't think you're using the term "total order" in its standard mathematical sense. Please define what you mean by a "total order".

Comment: You can compare something in A or in B or in some fixed enumeration of the countable set. What you're doing here seems to be comparing apples to gravel.

Comment: Is it not clear? Conceiving of $A$, $B$ as functions from $S$ to $\mathbb{N}$, how many elements $s \in S$ have $A(s) \geq B(s)$? Can this number ever be finite? For $S$ countable there must exist functions to $\mathbb{N}$ by definition, and by total order I just mean one such function.

Comment: So you're using "total order" to mean "enumeration"? Or else, where is the comparison taking place? If $S$ carries two linear orders $<_1$ and $<_2$, and also two enumerations $A$ and $B$, what do you even mean by that? And if no, then where do you compare $A$ and $B$? In $\Bbb N$? You just said that the domain is $\Bbb N$ not $S$, so what is $S$? And if you're just asking about functions, why not just ask it like that: given two functions $F,G\colon\Bbb{N\to N}$, is it necessarily the case that infinitely many elements satisfy $F(n)<G(n)$? In which case, no, just take $G(n)=0$.

Comment: Yes I am using those terms interchangeably. A correction to my previous comment, is that $A$ and $B$ are injective functions. I don't believe that I said the domain is $\mathbb{N}$, but of course you can think of $S=\mathbb{N}$ if that helps.

Comment: I beg to differ. The version of the comment that I saw said that they are functions ***from*** $\Bbb N$. That, at least in standard jargon, mean that they are functions whose domain is $\Bbb N$. Please don't try to cast me as misreading your original comment, which was edited 7 times.

Comment: Oh, also "total order" is not interchangeable with an injective function from $\Bbb N$ into a set $S$. I don't know where you learned this, but it would be wise to unlearn that. If you want to cast your question in terms of injections from $\Bbb N$, that's fine. But you should be very clear as to what you mean and make sure that you don't misuse existing standard terminology. This is just part of communicating with people.

Comment: I didn't mean to come across as confrontational. I was honestly kind of intimidated asking this question because I thought I wouldn't phrase it properly, which is why I got flustered and kept making mistakes in my comment, you're probably right and one version did say 'from' $\mathbb{N}$ by mistake. Would the following be clearer: given a countable set $S$ and and two bijections $A: \rightarrow \mathbb{N}, B: \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$, will there always be infinitely many elements $s \in S$ with $A(s) \geq B(s)$?

Comment: In my opinion the formulation in your last comment is much clearer, except that I'd write $A:S\to\mathbb N,B:S\to\mathbb N$ instead of $A:\to\mathbb N,B:\to\mathbb N$ which looks weird.

Comment: Ok thanks. Is it correct to refer to these functions as enumerations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering the version in your 4th comment, Yes.
Combining the inverse of B with A the question becomes: if $f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ is a bijection, can there be only finitely many n with $f(n) \geq n$. To see not, suppose there is and let $M = max \{f(n) : f(n) \geq n \} $. Now look at the image of $\{1,2,...,M+1 \}$.

Comment: Ah yes, thank you, that's what I was looking for. I edited the question, just in case you want to edit the answer correspondingly at all.